# Equation to draw a budget graph

Tags: graphing-functions

Say I have $50,000 in cash, and need a loan for the rest of a house.

Holding the loan-to-value constant at 80%, how can I plot the amount of remaining cash against the price of the house?

```
y = ...?
```

Sorry if this is far too easy for this site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the graph of remaining cash vs the price of the house, then it's just simply

$$y=50000-\frac x5$$, where $x$ is the price of the house (with a maximum of $250$K that you can afford since you're putting $20\%$ down for the mortgage); and $y$ is the money that you have left in your pocket after putting a $20\%$ down payment.

Here's the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y=50000-x/5&lk=4&num=3) generated by Wolframalpha.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted! Thanks you very much, you're very clever!